# Unable to run Kotlin program in terminal

Tags: kotlin

I tried a simple Hello World Program in Kotlin.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
println("HelloWorld!")
}
```

But when I tried to compile it in terminal,

```
kotlinc HelloWorld.kt -include-runtime -d HelloWorld.jar
```

I get the following.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/preloading/Preloader : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Comment: There's a version mismatch between the JDK you're using and the version used to compile the jar. Make sure JAVA_HOME equals what you think it should.

Comment: What's the JDK version you are using to run it?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ It's Open JDK 1.7.0_101

Comment: You should use JDK 1.8

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` states that you should be using version `1.8.x`...just upgrade and the error should vanish. The `-jvm-target 1.8` switch might be also helpful...

Comment: Thanks all. It worked

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin compiler requires Java 8 to run the compilation process.  You can still target Java 6 bytecode or Java 8 bytecode as you wish, but you must use a Java 8 or newer JDK during compilation.  This was announced in the [Kotlin 1.1.2 release announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/04/kotlin-1-1-2-is-out/).

Under "Migration Notes":

> The Kotlin compiler now requires JDK 8 to run. You shouldn’t notice any changes, because most other Java development tools such as Gradle and the Android toolchain also require JDK 8, so you almost certainly already have it installed. For code generated by the compiler, Java 1.6 compatibility is still the default, and we have no plans to drop support for generating Java 1.6 compatible bytecode.

Comment: Thanks for your info :-)